# Get the tagName element inside class

Tags: javascript, html, tagname

I want to get the element of `a` inside class and change it.

My HTML is:

```
<div class="alignleft">
    <a href="http://cismdomain.com/articles/page/2/">« Older Entries</a>
</div>
```

I want to change `Older Entries` to `Previous`.

My JavaScript code is:

```
var oldentries = document.querySelector('.alignleft');
var ainside = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
oldentries.ainside.innerHTML = "Previous";
```

but that gives me `undefined`.

Answer (score 3):

Once you use [Document.querySelector()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) to get the elements with class `'.alignleft'` you can also do `oldentries.querySelector('a');` to get the `'a'` element within `oldentries` and then change the [element.innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML):

```js
var oldentries = document.querySelector('.alignleft'),
    ainside = oldentries.querySelector('a');

ainside.innerHTML = 'Previous';
```

```html
<div class="alignleft">
  <a href="http://cismdomain.com/articles/page/2/">« Older Entries</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to update the `textContent` property of the `<a>` element.

**Working Example:**

```js
var linkElement = document.querySelector('.alignleft a');
linkElement.textContent = 'Previous';
```

```html
<div class="alignleft">
<a>Older Entries</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementsByTagName` returns a HTML Collection. So you need to iterate over it (in your case it would be the first entry).

```
var oldentries = document.querySelector('.alignleft');
var ainside = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
for(i=0;i<ainside.length;i++) {
    ainside[i].innerHTML = "Previous";
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

You can look for your element using a signle call to querySelector by using a more precise selector : Directly use `.alignLeft a` instead of doing it twice.

This code works :

```
var entries = document.querySelector('.alignLeft a');
entries.innerHTML = "Previous"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code would render out to something like

```
document.querySelector('.alignleft').document.getElementsByTagName('a').innerHTML = "Previous";
```

Also, `getElementsByTagName('a')` would render an Array not an object which you can apply `.innerHTML` to.

```
var ainside = document.querySelector('.alignlef a'); // Select first occurance of a inside the first occurance of .alignleft in the document

ainside.innerHTML = "Previous";
```